# Write JSON Response to Var JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

When I try to get the request-response with Postman I receive

```
{score_stacker":25}
```

Now I want the response saved to a javascript `var`, trying

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/api/getTenthStacker', true);
  request.send();
  var tenthstacker = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Now I get a console syntax error

> "unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data", when I use stringify I just have an empty var

What shall I do?

Comment: You should re-read the doc of XMLHttpRequest, it is not synchrone, you have to use callback to get the response.

Comment: *"What shall I do?"* Use `fetch` instead and learn about promises or `async`/`await`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not a valid JSON response.

It should be (missing a quote):

```
{"score_stacker":25}
```